# Cannot implicitly convert string to bool

Tags: c#

I am trying to make code in a windows form application (visual studios) that should take in text from a text box and check if it is saying something in peculiar and do the operation the text box says, for example if it says "1 + 1" the other text box (in the code it is called "output") should say "2". please check my code and just saying I am a beginner. Also i did try a few things like "Convert.ToBoolean(string)" but it didn't work.

```
      private void TextEditor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextEditor.Text = "";
        Convert.ToBoolean(TextEditor);

        if (TextEditor.Text = "1 + 1")
        {
            Output.Text = "2";
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean();` is a function and your are eating up the returned value. Also the argument shouldn't be of type `Control` like in your case, but something that _can_ be converted into boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: I don't think you need the line (actually, you're not even using the return value of `ToBoolean`)

```
Convert.ToBoolean(TextEditor);
```

Secondly, you'd get an exception thrown, as you can't convert a textBox to a boolean value - you'd have to something like this:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(TextEditor.Text);
```

But I don't think this is useful in this context, so leave it away.

Thirdly, you only used one equality operator - this should do:

```
if (TextEditor.Text == "1 + 1")
//...
```

Otherwise you assign the text of the texteditor with "1+1" and check afterwards wether the assignment result (this is what was assigned, so  in that case it's "1 + 1") is true. Obviously, as the assignment was a string, it can't be true, so the compiler tells you that you can't convert a string ("1 + 1") to bool.

Anyway, if you want to write a calculator, I wouldn't hardcode every result of every calculation. E.g. for addition you could do something like this:

```
Output.Text = TextEditor.Text.Split('+').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Trim())).Sum().ToString();
```

This takes the text, splits it at the + sign (It'd be the same for subtraction or other stuff), converts the (trimmed) operands to integers and sums them, using LINQ.

However, as your numbers *could be wrong* (your comment pointed to something like that), you should surround this with a `try catch` - and, as you don't want an empty input to result in an error, you could add the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option:

```
try
{
    Output.Text = TextEditor.Text.Split(new []{'+'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Trim())).Sum().ToString();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Output.Text = "Wrong input!";
}
```

Comment: @MetaColon but the way you did "Output.Text = TextEditor.Text.Split('+').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Trim())).Sum();" iot gives an error saying you can't implicitly convert string to integer

Comment: @MetaColon this error comes up when i run "Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Why are the answers all saying that the *compiler* should complain about `Convert.ToBoolean` being passed a `Control`? Sure it makes no sense and you'd get a runtime error. But it *will* compile; the method has an overload which accepts an `object` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx (though it will  throw if not `IConvertible`)

Comment: @DrummingAce now you shouldn't encounter those problems anymore.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 hey don't ask me about that i'm a noob at this

Comment: @MetaColon ok ya it fixed it! thankyou once again you were a lot of help!

Comment: @DrummingAce I thought the problem was solved, so why isn't the answer marked as an answer anymore?

Comment: @MetaColon it is i don't know why it did that! there i fixed it! you were the greatest help i could ever ask for i am sorry that this happened. My humble apologize

Answer (score 3):

if requires a Boolean operator, in this case '==' :)

```
if (TextEditor.Text == "1 + 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

```
    TextEditor.Text = "";
```

You don't want to do this because you're clearing out whatever the user entered.

```
    Convert.ToBoolean(TextEditor);
```

This isn't needed because you don't store or use the result. It won't actually convert `TextEditor` to a boolean "in place." Also, this shouldn't compile, it should be `TextEditor.Text`.

```
    if (TextEditor.Text = "1 + 1")
```

As others have indicated, this is assignment (not comparison), which is the cause of the problem. This is like saying

```
if ("1 + 1")
```

which isn't a boolean.

Also, as others have indicated, you don't want to hardcode this because what if people did, for example, "1 + 2"? Also, what if they typed it differently, like "1+1"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to build an interpreter. You should look into `Regular Expressions` and `Expression Trees`. I won't lie, it's not very simple, but the result will be awesome if you follow through. You could create your own language on top of C#.

Comment: You don't really need regular expressions here I don't think.

Comment: I think he provided the "1 + 1 should result in 2" as an example of an acceptable operation. I may have read too much into the question though. I thought maybe the author wanted at least something like "[value_0][0 or more spaces][operator][0 or more spaces][value_1]". And maybe more. I may have read way too much into it now that I think of it.

Comment: You can't use RegEx to do a full arithmetic parser anyway because it requires recursion.

Comment: I heard compilers and interpreters use Regular Expressions to do their job, but I may be wrong.

Comment: No, parsers don't work that way, they need to use recursion.

Comment: Ok then. So, Regular Expressions and recursion? My idea is that the author is trying to build an interpreter. I imagine it would have to search the code for certain patterns and I cannot imagine how without Regular Expressions. I would assume it would not take one single pass to parse a piece of code for all of its tokens, I guess that's where the recursion is coming from?